# Angular OnPush Change Detection Propagation to a Child Components in a ngFor Loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

I am having an issue with onPush Change Detection in an Angular app.

I have created a demo app that illustrates the problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcebqu

The application contains a `parent` component and a `child` component.

Both `parent` and `child` are using onPush Change Detection.

Both `parent` and `child` have inputs broken out into getters and setters, with `this.cd.markForCheck();` being used in the setters.

```
    private _element: any;

    @Output()
    elementChange = new EventEmitter<any>();

    @Input()
    get element() {
        return this._element;
    }

    set element(newVal: any) {
        if (this._element === newVal) { return; }
        this._element = newVal;
        this.cd.markForCheck();
        this.elementChange.emit(this._element);
    }
```

The `parent` component creates several `child` components using a `*ngFor` loop, like so:

```
<app-child 
    *ngFor="let element of item.elements; let index = index; trackBy: trackElementBy" 
    [element]="item.elements[index]"
    (elementChange)="item.elements[index]=$event"></app-child>
```

The problem is, if the data is updated in the `parent` component, the changes are not being propogated down the the `child` component(s).

In the demo app, click the 'change' button and notice that the first 'element' in the 'elements' array ( `elements[0].order` ) is updated in the parent, but the change does not show in the the first `child` component's 'element'. However, if OnPush change detection is removed from the `child` component, it works properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the input passed in to the child component isn't an Array, IterableDiffers won't work.  [KeyValueDiffers](https://angular.io/api/core/KeyValueDiffers) however can be used in this case to watch for changes in the input object and then handle it accordingly ([stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7yw99?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts)):

```
  import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  KeyValueDiffers,
  KeyValueDiffer,
  EventEmitter,
  Output, Input
} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  private _element: any;

  @Output()
  elementChange = new EventEmitter<any>();


  get element() {
    return this._element;
  }

  @Input()
  set element(newVal: any) {
    if (this._element === newVal) { return; }
    this._element = newVal;
    this.cd.markForCheck();
    this.elementChange.emit(this._element);
  }

  private elementDiffer: KeyValueDiffer<string, any>;

  constructor(
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private differs: KeyValueDiffers
  ) {
    this.elementDiffer = differs.find({}).create();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    // or here
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    const changes = this.elementDiffer.diff(this.element);
    if (changes) {
      this.element = { ...this.element };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding an alternative solution just in case someone else gets this problem. The main reason why ChildComponent doesn't reflect the new value in its template is because only the property 'order' of 'element' is getting changed from the parent component, so the parent is injecting the same object reference with a modified 'order' property.

OnPush change detection strategy will only 'detect changes' when a new object reference is injected into the component. So in order for ChildComponent (which has OnPush change detection strategy) to trigger change detection, you have to inject a new object reference to the "element" input property instead of the same.

To see this in action, open https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcebqu and make ff changes.

> on file `parent.component.ts`, modify the method `onClick($event) {...}` to:

```
onClick(event){
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  this.item.elements[0] = {...this.item.elements[0], order: random};
}
```

The last line replaces the object reference inside the array at index 0 with a new object identical to old first element in the array, except for the order property.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `@Input()` decorator to the **setter** method.

```
get element() {
    return this._element;
}

@Input()
set element(newVal: any) {
    this._element = newVal;
}
```

Also here are some other things:

- Angular won't set duplicate values because `OnPush` only sets inputs when they have changed.
- Do not call `this.cd.markForCheck()` in a *setter* because the component is already dirty.
- You don't have to output the value from the input. The parent component already knows what was inputted.

Comment: Thanks cgTag. I tried your suggestions here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bc4tc7, unfortunately they did not work for me.